# Android Change image without a drawable

Tags: java, android, view, imagebutton, android-framelayout

I have a fragment that has a list of text views and buttons. There is an image button that when clicked allows me to select a picture. I want to change the image in the button to match the picture selected.

When the image button is clicked, the user can choose from a list of images on the database and I am returned the view selected. I've looked at other questions and I saw to change the image you need it to be a drawable which does not work in my case. Therefore, I've tried to use a FrameLayout and add the view (view contains the image) but I get an error: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Method below is called when image is selected an the fragment is about to close:

```
ImageButton i = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pic);
i.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

FrameLayout f = (FrameLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
f.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
f.addView(newPic); //error occurs on this line

getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
```

The image button is what I am aiming to have over the frame layout. Is there a way to keep the image button? If not, why am I getting an error if I am removing the view from the child's parent?

Comment: where you initialize `newPic` ?

Comment: Have you read ImageButton documentation?